# R read_delim() changes values when reading data

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to read in a tabstop seperated csv file using `read_delim()`. For some reason the function seems to change some field entries in integer values:

```
# Here some example data
# This should have 3 columns and 1 row 
file_string = c("Tage\tID\tVISITS\n19.02.01\t2163994407707046646\t40")

# reading that data using read_delim()
data = read_delim(file_string, delim = "\t")

view(data)
data$ID
2163994407707046656 # This should be 2163994407707046646
```

I totally do not understand what is happening here. If I chnage the col type to character the entry stays the same. Does anyone has an explanation for this?

Happy about any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your number has so many digits, that it does not fit into the R object. According to the specification IEEE 754, the precision of `double` is 53 bits which is approx. a number with 15 decimal digits. You reach that limit using  `as.double("2163994407707046646")`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the super quick answer! So what would be the proper way to convert it to int or dbl?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bignum/vignettes/precision.html